# Session Crashed in Google Colab at the begining of first epoch in TimeDistributed CNN model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

I'm working with video classification of 5 classes and using **TimeDistributed CNN** model in **Google Colab** platform. The train dataset contains **80** videos containing **75 frames** each. The validation dataset contains **20** videos containing **75 frames** each. So,in total I'm working with **100** videos.The **batch** size I used is **64**. But,at the beginning of first epoch,**session** gets **crashed** and ram usage gets full.
What should I need to modify to avoid this problem?

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([

    tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(Conv2D(64, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'),input_shape=(75,128, 128, 3)),
    tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D((2, 2))),
    tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(Conv2D(64, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu')),
    tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D((2, 2))),
    tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(Conv2D(128, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu')),
    tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(Conv2D(128, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu')),
    tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D((2, 2))),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='softmax')
])

from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0001),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit_generator(
      train_generator,
      validation_data=validation_generator, 
      validation_steps=1500//64, 
      shuffle=False,    
      steps_per_epoch=8,  
      epochs=5,
      verbose=1)
```

The message that I get:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From <ipython-input-11-c79b34d1df07>:8: Model.fit_generator (from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.training) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please use Model.fit, which supports generators.
Epoch 1/5
```

And then,a popup arises and tells me session crashed!!
Can anyone help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google colab has a very limited ~11 Gb memory for both your data and model. From the details, it's pretty obvious it is a memory issue and not related to model itself.

You can try reduce your dataset so that the memory is not exhausted also add your data processing pipeline for a better look.

Comment: Can you give me some info about  data processing pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

You could try a tensorflow's Dataset module. For example, instead of passing a array of images, you pass a list of image path's, the dataset generator at the time of training will only partially load 1 batch of images at a time. This way you won't overwhelm the memory. Here's an example

```
def preprocess_image(filename):
    """
    Load the specified file as a JPEG image, preprocess it and
    resize it to the target shape.
    """

    image_string = tf.io.read_file(filename)
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_string, channels=3)
    image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, tf.float32)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, target_shape)
    return image

images = [str(os.path.join(images_path ,f)) for f in os.listdir(images_path)]
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(images)
dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1024)
dataset = dataset.map(preprocess_image)
```

source: https://keras.io/examples/vision/siamese_network/